# Running the Create-React-App server independently in an app built with .NET Core 2.1 Template using Visual Studio 17 and "dotnet new reactredux"

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

**The Issue:**

To run the CRA server independently, Microsoft recommends [we run the CRA app separately and change the code within the Startup.cs class file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/react?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#run-the-cra-server-independently), like so:

Run the React app from the Console:

> > cd ClientApp
>
> > npm start

Replace `spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer` invocation inside *Startup.cs* with:

> spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:3000/");

However, when I hit F5, Visual Studio always launches a CRA server every time, at http://localhost:54789

[image]

**Steps to Reproduce:**

1. Install Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017
2. Choose the `.NET Core cross-platform development` build, during Visual Studio installation

[image]

3. Download and install npm from [the NPM website](https://www.npmjs.com/get-npm)
4. Open a Windows command-line tool
5. Navigate to a new workspace directory `cd \path\to\workspace\`
6. Run `npm install`
7. Ensure you have the latest .NET templates:  `dotnet new --install Microsoft.DotNet.Web.Spa.ProjectTemplates::2.0.0`
8. Create a new React-Redux app from the template:  `dotnet new reactredux`
9. Navigate into the ClientApp directory:  `cd ClientApp`
10. Run the CRA server:  `npm start`
11. Open your workspace directory in Windows Explorer
12. Open the .csproj file which was created (should open in Visual Studio 2017)
13. Replace the `spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer` invocation inside *Startup.cs* with:

> spa.UseProxyToSpaDevelopmentServer("http://localhost:3000/");

14. Hit **F5**

**Environment**:

- Microsoft Windows 7 Enterprise SP1
- Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2017 Version 15.6.7
- Microsoft .NET Framework 4.7.02558
- Node.js 8.11.1
- Node Package Manager 5.6.0
- .NET Core SDK 2.1.104
- Package References:

  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All 2.0.0`

  `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Extensions 2.0.0-rc1-final`

Am I just misunderstanding how this feature is supposed to work?

Comment: Where you able to figure this out? I'm on the same boat, and I feel like I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: I never was able to figure it out.  

Comment: I decided to continue as is, and I think that this is basically how it's supposed to work.

We are able to start and end the server without having to re-start the CRA server, which still saves a lot of time.